# iOS - Screen capture a video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, avcapturesession

UIGetScreenImage() is a private API of Apple and they won't let me use it.  I was using it to take a snapshot image of a full screen video and then saving the snapshot to the photo album.  They suggest I in turn use [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html) to get my "screenshot" for my video.  But the issue is I am streaming live video and am unsure if the capture session will allow me to take a snapshot of the playing video.  Any suggestions?  If this doesn't work is there an Open-GL solution that would work?